# How to revert a resize on jQuery resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-resizable

I want to revert the resizable element to its original state after the resize stop event. I am doing it with following code but this approach is not neat, the wrapper and the image now have same size and the re-sizing handle is displaced by one pixel because of this.

```
$images.resizable({ handles: 'all', stop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).find(".ui-resizable").add($(this)).css(ui.originalSize);
  }
});
```

Is there a neat way to achieve this?

Here is the jsfiddle link. Please use firefox. Notice how the resizing handles are displaced by one pixel after revert from above code.
http://jsfiddle.net/rohhittt/j2JU6/105/
Thanks

Comment: how about providing a fiddle, so we don't have to setup everything on our own? :)

Comment: Alright. Fiddle coming in a min.

Comment: It is difficult to find the difference. Could u please provide a screen shot? Also, if we reisize left side, the image position gets changed. If it is an issue, please note it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following snippet in the stop callback,

```
// Move the element to its original position.
ui.element.css(ui.originalPosition);
// Modify the element's width& height to the original value.
ui.element.css(ui.originalSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this part in a variable `$(this).css(ui.originalSize);`

Comment: This will not move the element back to its position.

Answer (score 0):

The width and size of the JQuery Dialog in JQuery 1.11.3 is retained even after resizing the dialog by commenting the below 2 lines of

```
stop: function( event, ui ) of 
this.uiDialog.resizable({ in ui.dialog
//options.height = that.uiDialog.height();
//options.width = that.uiDialog.width();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ui.element.css(ui.originalSize);
```

that does the trick

Comment: Is this your answer or you just confirm that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20729618/7404943) works?